# vlookup in excel/google drive

Tags: excel, vlookup

Im sorry this is a very basic question but for some reason it's just eluding me.

I'm trying to do a VLOOKUP in a table and I keep getting an error when trying to look up a string value.

I have created the problem on google drive to help illustrate what i mean
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L70yQeWmr0J08UwK3nkSQaLNVFzfI1zi8euzhoYq8XY/edit?usp=sharing

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) is intended to return a value that is to the right of the look up value. To reverse this, use a [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair.

```
=index(A:A, match("Danton", B:B, 0))
```

btw, if you use TRUE (or omit) in the *range_lookup* parameter, the lookup column needs to be sorted.

Comment: Thanks @Jepeed and others that helped on the sheet.

Comment: I found this to also work 
`=VLOOKUP("Danton",B2:C10,2,FALSE)`

Comment: @c4binever - The *Employee_no* numbers repeated in column C from column A were not originally there. I believe they were added to proved VLOOKUP's must-be-right-of-the-lookup syntax.