# Using an =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I am using an =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP to check two columns for matching values on any line, returning a yes or no with a match.

Now each value has a simple date on the row also and I want to find the difference in days for the rows returning yes, my issue is I cannot pin point the relating dates as I cannot tell exactly where each yes answer is coming from as all I'm getting back from my first formula is yes/no.

any help would be appreciated

Edit -

=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(D2,'Completed installs'!D:D,1,0)),"No","Yes") Returns my yes/no value, I am looking to locate the date on the row of the 'completed installs' !D:D which returned my yes value, for this example the date column is B

Comment: If the two values match, wouldn't the difference be zero? I'm pretty sure that I'm not understanding your question, so if you could edit your question to include some sample data it would help.

Comment: @DeanOC Edited slightly, is that any clearer?

Comment: If you are trying to return a value to the right of the lookup column use VLOOKUP. If you are trying to return a value from the left of the lookup column, use an INDEX/MATCH pair. See [vlookup in excel/google drive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642573/vlookup-in-excel-google-drive/33642638#33642638).

Comment: A bit clearer. Can you confirm that you want to find the cell reference in the 'Completed installs'!D:D column which has the value matching the value in D2?

Answer (score 0):

This will return the corresponding date:

```
=INDEX('Completed Installs'!B:B,MATCH(D2,'Completed Installs'!D:D,0),1)
```

If you want a single formula that either returns "NO" or the date, then use this:

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX('Completed Installs'!B:B,MATCH(D2,'Completed Installs'!D:D,0),1)),"No",INDEX('Completed Installs'!B:B,MATCH(D2,'Completed Installs'!D:D,0),1))
```